Duplicate vote followed by off-topic vote in Staging Ground closes a question as off-topic for reason duplicate
When 2 reviewers both cast duplicate votes on a Staging Ground post, the question is marked as a duplicate as expected:

When a question has a duplicate vote and then someone casts an off-topic vote, the question is marked as off-topic with the reason duplicate instead, producing this:

I am quite sure that is not supposed to happen. There probably is not supposed to be some off-topic as duplicate separate from duplicate in Staging Ground questions.
Note: The author is still able to see the question that their question was closed as a duplicate of in the blue banner in either case.

This bug was pretty much already reported during the beta (it's the same except that the status was "Duplicate" with the off-topic modal and no off-topic comment) but that bugreport wasn't addressed or marked as planned or similar.

This seems to happen at least in part because the Duplicate close reason is behind an "off-topic" submenu. That label is wrong; it seems intended to group close reasons for unfixable questions.

This also happens the other way round: if a question has an off-topic vote, voting it as a duplicate closes the question as a duplicate, but with the off-topic banner: example / screenshot
